# django fileuploader chunk method not working as expected

Tags: python, django

**strong text**the Django chunks method on the fileuploader handler accepts chunk_size with this desc in the source code

```
 ""
        Read the file and yield chunks of ``chunk_size`` bytes (defaults to
        ``File.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE``).
 """
```

so i have this view function,

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['image']:
        file = request.FILES['image']
        print(sys.getsizeof(file))
        chunk_size = 0
        dd = list(file.chunks(chunk_size=20000))
        print(len(dd[0]))  // this gives me some figures like the size of the image
        print('...')
        for chunk in list(file.chunks(chunk_size=10000)):
            chunk_size += sys.getsizeof(chunk)
        print(chunk_size)
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

and this is the chunks function implementation in django

```
 def chunks(self, chunk_size=None):
        """
        Read the file and yield chunks of ``chunk_size`` bytes (defaults to
        ``File.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE``).
        """
        chunk_size = chunk_size or self.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE
        try:
            self.seek(0)
        except (AttributeError, UnsupportedOperation):
            pass

        while True:
            data = self.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data
```

generally, I was expecting to the length of the generated list to be filesize/chunk_size but rather I get the size of the image, i don't understand why, can someone please help me with an explanation?

Comment: where are you expecting to see this 5? what do you get instead?

Comment: @Sayse   i saw something like the size of the image in bytes